# Ring-theoretic version of a  matrix problem

Tags: matrix-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, orthogonal-matrices

Problem #17 in Zhan's [survey](http://math.ecnu.edu.cn/~zhan/papers/ZhanICCM.pdf) of open problems in matrix theory is the Li-Poon problem on writing a square real matrix as the linear combination of $k$ orthogonal matrices. They proved that it is possible to take $k=4$ for every square real matrix and asked if $k$ is the least possible such number.

I am wondering if there is a ring-theoretical version of this conjecture. This raises some even more basic questions:

> What is the ring-theoretic equivalent
>   of an orthogonal matrix?

And since an orthogonal matrix $O$ can be characterized as satisfying $OO^{T}=I$,

> What is the ring-theoretic equivalent
>   of the matrix transpose operation?

Comment: What do you mean by ring-theoretic? Replace the ground field by a ring, or replace the matrix ring by a ring? Is the ring commutative or noncommutative?

Comment: Probably too general, but a starting point could be a ring $R$ with an anti-automorphism $t:R\to R$ of order $2$. Then $O(R):=\{x\in U(R)|t(x)=x^{-1}\}$, where $U(R)$ denotes the units of $R$.

Comment: For the ring version of "transpose", I think the story begins here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/*-algebra

Comment: (the link is broken, but it points to the wiki page for 'star algebra' )

Comment: Felix, it is a mistake. A sum of four orthogonal matrices cannot be arbitrary large. Clearly, the matrix $100I$ is NOT a sum of four orthogonal matrices.

Comment: In the linked survey of Zhan, the result mentioned is a linear combination of 4 orthogonal matrices.  Along the same lines, I (with David Radcliffe) discovered that for all orders n and many rings R (including fields), with finitely many exceptions every matrix is the sum of exactly two invertible matrices.  If I find the MathOverflow question related to this, I will return with a link.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Matrix Sums" Paseman, 2013.02.08

Comment: ... they study **linear combinations** (not just sums) of orthogonal matrices.

Comment: @Anton: My bad. As Andreas pointed out, I misquoted the survey - Li & Poon referred to linear combinations, not sums. Sorry.

Comment: @Suvrit: Did you mean $C^{*}$-algebra?

Comment: @darijgrinberg: I mean replacing the matrix ring by a ring, or perhaps by an algebra. So I want to deal with $a \in R$ being the sum/linear combination of $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{k}$ that belong to some special subset $O \subseteq R$.

Comment: @Felix: No, I meant just $*$-algebra ($*$-rings, etc...)